# human activity recognition in a long unsegmented video sequence

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

I know I can do a bag-of-features based activity recognition/classification on pre-segmented video clips. Now I have this need to analyze the construction worker's workflow from videos. For example, I have a video capturing a worker working on bricklaying. Let say, in this video, the worker has finished 10 bricks. How do I recognize the activity (bricklaying) while also count the cycle numbers (10 times) or even segment each cycle exactly?

Comment: Where to start? This sort of analysis - video based activity recognition in cluttered, unstructured scenes - is an open topic of research. I can only assume you are asking this question because you are perhaps approaching it more from a construction management point-of-view (i.e. a measurement based on the analysis of worker productivity and completion rates)? 

I only ask because - as Computer Vision researcher - I once had to collaborate with those in the construction domain. The overarching challenge was in adjusting their expectations as to what was remotely feasible to extract from video.

Comment: P.S. You say you have already have your “bag-of-words” - but how have you already achieved this? If you have managed to already extract discriminatory features from the video successfully, then surely you are well underway to solving this?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm standing at the construction management view for productivity analysis. Application of computer vision in construction domain is sort of new in recent years. This is a really tiny research field so I probably even know (or at least heard of) your research partner. I just adopt other people's code for features extraction and quantization. Now I can do action classification on segmented video clips. But still underway on how to do joint segmentation and recognition on unsegmented video, which is natually the need on construciton workflow analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Activity recognition in single activity sequence is done using deep learning. Multiple action detection in video sequence is also done. All these come under the Activity-net challenge which is hosted almost every year. In the github repos given as references, you can find all the classes that the model is able to recognise, if the class that you are looking for(bricklaying, et al) is not there and if you have proper training dataset, code for retraining the network is also given. One can use that to include those required classes.

References:

[Temporal Segment networks - For single action recognition](https://github.com/yjxiong/temporal-segment-networks)

[Multiple Activity Detection](https://github.com/imatge-upc/activitynet-2016-cvprw)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.